# Remove tag appcelerator-mobile on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

From [today](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/01/embracing-stack-overflow-for-appcelerator-community-support/) the Appcelerator team decided to use [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as a support platform (with the [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator) tag). On Stack Overflow there are two main tag related to Appcelerator: [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator) and [appcelerator-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator-mobile). I think the best solution is to incorporate the two tags in only one, the [appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appcelerator) tag.